# Trouble setting up LSTM model for multivariate time series forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, tensorflow2.0, forecasting

I having issues with how many number of LSTMs to have for a multi-variate forecasting.

The dataset I'm working on:
[Weather Dataset (kaggle)](https://www.kaggle.com/muthuj7/weather-dataset)

```
df_final = df.loc['2011-01-01':'2014-10-31']
df_final['Temperature (C)'].plot(figsize=(28,6))
```

[image: Temperature Plot:]

In the end I want to forecast temperature.(other paremeters too, but mainly temperature)

The data has hourly readings.

```
# How many rows per month?
rows_per_months=24*30

test_months = 12 #number of months we want to predict in the future.

test_indices = test_months*720
test_indices

# train and test split:
train = df_final.iloc[:-test_indices]

# Choose the variable/parameter you want to predict
test = df_final.iloc[-test_indices:]

len(train)
#[op]: 24960

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

scaled_train = scaler.fit_transform(train)
scaled_test = scaler.transform(test)

#define generator:
length =  rows_per_months#Length of output sequences (in number of timesteps)
batch_size = 30 #Number of timeseries sample in batch
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train,scaled_train,length=length,batch_size=batch_size)
```

**Defining Model**

```
# define model
model = Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, input_shape=(length,scaled_train.shape[1])))
#NOTE: Do not specify the activation function for LSTM layers, this is because it will not run on GPU.
model.add(Dense(scaled_train.shape[1]))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

After training,

[image: Loss graph]

**Evaluating the model on Test Data:**

```
first_eval_batch = scaled_train[-length:]
first_eval_batch.shape

first_eval_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((1,length,scaled_train.shape[1]))

n_features = scaled_test.shape[1] #n_features = scaled_train.shape[1] =250 (for predicting all parameters in the next time stamp)
# print(n_features) = 1 #Since we are only predicting temperature.
test_predictions = []

first_eval_batch = scaled_train[-length:]
current_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((1, length, n_features))
print(current_batch.shape)

#output:(1, 720, 4)

for i in range(len(test)):
    #Get prediction 1 time stamp ahead
    current_pred = model.predict(current_batch)[0]
    #store prediction
    test_predictions.append(current_pred)

    #update the current batch to now include the prediction and drop the first value.
    current_batch = np.append(current_batch[:,1:,:],[[current_pred]],axis=1)

true_predictions = pd.DataFrame(data=true_predictions,columns=test.columns,index=test.index)

true_predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predictions)
```

The resultant Dataframe:

```
result_df = pd.concat([test['Temperature (C)'], true_predictions['Temperature (C)']],axis=1)

result_df.plot(figsize=(28,8))
```

[image: Prediction of temperature for test data]

**Since the model does not predict the correct value of test data, I cannot proceed further with the forecasting.**

- How do I fix this?

**PS:**
I have tried playing with the number of layers and number of lstm units in layers but nothing seems to work. I have also tried to use different activation functions such as *relu* but it will take more than 20 hrs to finish 1 epoch, since the model wouldn't train on GPU unless the LSTMs have default functions (i.e *tanh*)